# Desigining a synchronous FSM

Tags: state-machines

I am trying to figure out how do I approach for a synchronous FSM as per the following information:

- Two inputs A, B & single output Z
- Two inputs A, B & single output Z
- Z=1 if A had the same value at each of two previous clock ticks.

or

- Z=1 if B=1 since last time the "condition above" was true (i.e A had the same value at each of two previous clock ticks)
- Otherwise Z=0.

I have understood the design to some extent but I am unable to understand how I have to decide what will be the next state in the state diagram?

How do I approach for such designs.

Comment: What language are you writing this in? (or do you just need a conceptual idea of how to go about it, e.g. a logic gate diagram)

Comment: @OliGlaser, I can undertsand if I get hint for state diagram. I am not implementing in HDL.

Comment: In the second condition, does Z=1 if B=1 *and* the last state of A was 1? (or Z? since you say "since the last time the condition above was true" - when you say i.e. "A=1", do you mean "Z=1"?) If you could clarify this a little it would help.

Comment: @SaadRafey Just for the sake of every one's eyes can you confirm this:  in your question's 3rd bullet:  "... the condition above" = "A had the same value at each of two previous clock ticks"?

Answer (score 1):

Since this sounds like a homework problem, I'm just going to give you a few hints to get you started, rather than a complete state diagram.

The key concept here is that you need to continually track the history of the A input, even while the Z output is being "held" on by the B input. This requires a minimum of 4 states (plus an "initial" state); Z is off for two of them and on for two of them.

If you're still stuck, leave a comment here and I'll add a sketch of the full state diagram.

ASIDE: Interestingly, knowing the abstract state machine doesn't help much with a practical implementation of the circuit, which can be realized with a pair of D-type master-slave flip-flops and four 2-input gates of various types.

[image: implementation schematic]

This implementation divides the problem into two separate state machines.
The output of U2 is high whenever the current and previous states of A are the same. U3-U6 form a special kind of S-R latch that is set whenever U2 is high, but reset only if both U2 and B are low.

EDIT: OK, here's the actual state machine. Each state is labeled with the output (Z) value. Each edge (arrow) leaving a state is labeled with the two input values (AB), and "x" denotes "don't care".

[image: state diagram]

I had initially started with a diagram that had 8 states, but I soon realized that there were two groups of three states each that could be combined, since the states in each group had the same output value and made all the same transitions. This allowed me to reduce the diagram to the four states shown here.

The optional fifth state on the left is simply to prevent a startup pulse on the output. Without it, the state machine assumes that the (non-existent) "previous" state of A was 0, so if the current state is also 0, the output will go high. The extra state prevents this. Note that the implementation shown above does not have this feature.

Comment: Thanks for your help,but I am still stuck.please add a sketch of full state diagram

Comment: @SaadRafey Did you try anything as of now? Can you post  some of your attempts? You can do this by editing your question and posting some of sketches or ideas under a separate heading.  This is how stackexchange websites work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use gates to determine what the next state will be.  You may have misssed the fact that you need to add some kind of "memory" so that you know which state you are in right now.  That's what flip-flops are for.  Then the gates you add will combine signals from the input with signals from the flip flops to produce the next state.

In a software-only situation, substitute state variables for the flip-flops.

Comment: Thanks for help.I am only trying to draw a state diagram

Comment: @SaadRafey can you prove that you are really trying something. People at Stackexchange help those who have already done some research..